# Fisher information of normal distribution with unknown mean and variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, fisher-information

**I am asked to find the fisher information contained in $X_1 \sim N(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ (ie: two unknown parameters, only one observation).  How would I find the Fisher information here?**

I know that with a sample $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n $~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma^2=1$, Fisher's information is given by : 
$$
-E(\frac{d^2}{d\mu^2} \ln f(x))=1/\sigma^2.
$$ 
Though this is the case with one paramter and I am not sure how it would map on to the case with two parameters. I imagine there is some use of a Hessian but I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

It will be the expected value of the Hessian matrix of $\ln f(x;\mu, \sigma^2)$. Specifically for the normal distribution, you can check that it will a diagonal matrix. The $\mathcal{I}_{11}$ you have already calculated. For the second diagonal term 
$$
\ln f(x;\mu, \sigma)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \sigma^2)+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2,
$$
$$
l'_{\sigma^2} = - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} - \frac{1}{2\sigma^4}(x-\mu)^2,
$$
hence
$$
\mathcal{I}_{22}= -\mathbb{E}[l''_{\sigma^2}]
=
- \mathbb{E} [ \frac{1}{2\sigma^4} - \frac{1}{\sigma^6}(x-\mu)^2]
 =
-\frac{1}{2\sigma^4} + \frac{2}{\sigma^4} = \frac{1}{2\sigma^4} .
$$
And for the non-diagonal terms 
$$
\mathcal{I}_{22}= -\mathbb{E}[l''_{\sigma^2,\mu}] =   - \mathbb{E}\frac{2(x-\mu)}{2\sigma^4} = 0.
$$

Comment: Can you say a bit more about that? What would be the entries in the Hessian?

Comment: If you let $l$ be the log-likelihood function and write $v\equiv \sigma^2$ for simplicity, the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of the log-likelihood function will be equal to $$\color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \mu^2} & \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \mu \partial v} \\ \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \mu \partial v} & \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial v^2}\end{bmatrix}}.$$Note that the Hessian is a symmetric matrix, so once you calculate the top right entry, you can copy it into the bottom left entry.

Comment: @jdoe pls see the edited answer